# How to add .html to the end of the permalink

Tags: permalinks

How do I add .html to the end of the permalink?

I tried changing the permalink structure to `/%postname%.html` but this did not work.

Comment: Changing permalink structure should be enough. What aspect of it is not working?

Comment: Simply that the .html was not appended onto the end of the postname.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache. Are you using any cache plugins? Your permalink structure must work, as this is the correct way in doing what you need.

Comment: I cleared the browser cache and the issue remains.

Comment: Use the following plugin for
[https://wordpress.org/plugins/html-in-url/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/html-in-url/)